# I get an error when I run expo start on my project. Anyone know a fix?

Tags: android, node.js, ubuntu-18.04

This is the error that I receive.

```
fs.js:1384
    throw error;
    ^
Error: watch /home/daniel/Documents/Glocal/app/Aqua-Client-Project/node_modules/expo-face-detector/android/src ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/daniel/Documents/Glocal/app/Aqua-Client-Project/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:175:20)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/Documents/Glocal/app/Aqua-Client-Project/node_modules/sane/src/common.js:116:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at /home/daniel/Documents/Glocal/app/Aqua-Client-Project/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at go$readdir$cb (/home/daniel/Documents/Glocal/app/Aqua-Client-Project/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:162:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

For background, I am trying to run an android app that I pulled from a student group's github. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

`ENOSPC` is short for "Error: No Space", and you can see it occurs when accessing `/home/daniel/Documents/Glocal/app/Aqua-Client-Project/node_modules/expo-face-detector/android/src`.

You should free up some space on the drive that holds `/home/daniel`.

Comment: Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on  <br />
/dev/sda8       77603556 40508948  33122820  56% /home